# Yii Framework: How to get the num_rows?

Tags: yii

As the [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao) does not say how to do a simply "num_rows" with their system, i need some help here: How to get the amount of rows in the result set ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming:

```
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
```

This will work for insert, update and delete:

```
$rowCount=$command->execute();
```

execute(): performs a non-query SQL statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. If successful, it returns the number of rows that are affected by the execution.

For select, you could do the following:

```
$dataReader=$command->query();
```

This generates the CDbDataReader instance and CDbDataReader provides a rowCount property

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbDataReader#rowCount-detail

```
$rowCount = $dataReader->rowCount;
```

About rowCount => Returns the number of rows in the result set. Note, most DBMS may not give a meaningful count. In this case, use "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName" to obtain the number of rows.

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object ($rowCount = $dataReader->rowCount;)

Answer (score 5):

ActiveRecord has [count](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#count-detail) method which can be used.

```
$cntCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
$cntCriteria->condition = "categoryId = :categoryId";
$cntCriteria->params[':categoryId'] = $categoryRow->categoryId;
$articleCount = Article::model()->count($cntCriteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to do this. When we execute a sql query it will return the result as array only. So we can able get the count of the rows using `count()` function like below.

```
$output=User::model()->findAllBySql("select * from user");//User is a model belongs to the user table
$count_val=count($output);//$count_val has the value of number of rows in the output.
```